# Set solution folder property in CMake for 3rd-party library

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

My project depends on a large 3rd party library (OpenMVG).
Currently it is not installed. Official building instructions recommend use it with `add_subdirectory`.

Therefore my `CMakeLists.txt` contain the following lines

```
add_subdirectory(${OpenMVG_DIR}/src "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/openMVG")
include_directories(${OpenMVG_INCLUDES})
add_executable(f_matching f_matching.cpp)
target_link_libraries(f_matching ${OpenMVG_LIBS})
```

My platform is the Visual Studio, and generated solution contains 72 projects on the top level. I'd like to use `FOLDER` CMake property to organize it in hierarchical levels. For example, I'd like to move all OpenMVG's projects to the separate VS solution folder.

However, as the CMake documentation says, this property can be only assigned to targets, not to directories.
My `CMakeLists.txt` contains

```
set_property(DIRECTORY ${OpenMVG_DIR}/src PROPERTY FOLDER OpenMVG)
```

but this line does nothing, no solution folders appear.
I've tried to modify a couple of OpenMVG's CMakeLists by setting `FOLDER` property on targets, this worked.

Is there any workaround for this situation, without changing CMakeLists from OpenMVG?
Currently, I'd like to spend my time for other tasks, and postpone this simple editing for future.

Comment: What's wrong with just calling `set_property` from your own CMakeLists for all of the 72 OpenMVG targets? Sure, it's a bit tedious, but you only have to do it once.

Comment: Yes, nothing wrong. Already done so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one 'hack' to achieve your goal. Original version of 'add_library' is prefixed with underscore, so you can re-implement top-level 'add_library' function in this way:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

# you need it to properly set variable from function() call
set(target_list "" CACHE INTERNAL "target_list")
function(add_library name)
    message("Adding library ${name}")
    set(target_list ${target_list} ${name} CACHE INTERNAL "target_list")
    _add_library(${name} ${ARGN})
endfunction()

# Your add_subdirectory() goes here

set_target_properties(${target_list} PROPERTIES FOLDER "OpenMVG")
```

Of course, it is not documented and not official as I know but it works, at least now with CMake 2.8.12.2.